# Editing Records in MS Access

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007, ms-access-2010

I am using MS Access (2002-2003 file format) and in the file I have a form.
When I click on the form, I get a table with records.
I would like to edit those records, and want that edited records are stored in the database.
However, the problem is every time I double click on the field I want to edit, I hear annoying sound from Windows, and cannot edit any field.

Has anyone a suggestion, how does record editing function in MS Access, and why can't I edit records? Do I have to enable something?

Thx

UPDATE: I found on google the recommendation, that I should change Recordsettyp from 'Dynaset' to 'Dynaset (inconsistent updates)'. When I did that, I could change records. However, is this allowed to do, and what consequences does this setting have?

Comment: Few things could cause the problem. First, check if the Form is allowed for Edits (Under `Property Sheet -> Data (Tab) ->Allow Edits (Property)`). Next thing to look would be the Recordsource. Sometime the Recordsource might be non-updatabale, check Why is my query read-only? - http://allenbrowne.com/ser-61.html

Comment: where do I find both properties? (I am using access in another language)

Comment: I found on google the recommendation, that I should change Recordsettyp from 'Dynaset' to 'Dynaset (Inkonsistente Aktualisierungen)'. When I did that, I could change records. However, is this allowed to do, and what consequences does this setting have?

Comment: http://www.access-programmers.co.uk/forums/showthread.php?t=18314

Comment: I have also read, that it would be the best thing not to use inconsistent updates. However, how can I avoid using it? Is there an alternative?

Comment: You're using a table or a query behind the form?  If it's a query, make sure the query is updateable.

Comment: How can I make sure that the query is updatable?

Comment: First of all, run the query.  If it's not updateable, it will say so in the bottom info bar.  If that is the case, make sure your query is within these guidelines: http://allenbrowne.com/ser-61.html

Comment: Hi guys! Strange thing is happening - on the form level, I changed Recordsettyp from 'Dynaset' to 'Dynaset (inconsistent updates)'. After doing that I could edit records. However, I read that this is not a good idea because it can cause inconsistencies. Therefore, I change it back. But after changing it back, I can still edit records. Can you please tell me what is going on, because with the same settings I couldn't before and now I can edit records... Confused... Looking forward to your answers!

Answer (score 0):

Two possibilities of why you cant edit.
1) the form should be editable in the properties.
2) if your form is getting information from a query. The query should be simple. I mean no totals or no bringing many fields from different tables which are one to many.
Solution to 2? Instead of getting data from that query. You should append that query into a table. And then get the data from that table and then update the real table.

Real table x > Append info you want to show in form to > table y > show in form > when close form, you update table x with y.

Hope it helps